# How to get Inno setup to display message with only a cancel button so the install stops

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using Inno setup to deliver a software package.  It detects the version of Access and pops up a message.  I want to make the message tell the user they have downloaded the wrong version and halt the installation.  Currently the Inno script uses

```
itd_downloadafter(NoRuntimePage.ID);
```

to display a message telling the user they need the AccessRuntime installed.  When they user presses next it downloads the AccessRuntime and continues.  I want to change this for my new script to tell the user they have the wrong version and then end the install script when they press next or just cancel.   Can anyone help me abit on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** *TLama's answer is more accurate.* **

You could use the InitializeWizard procedure to run the access check at the beginning... if it fails you should be able to show your message box then call  Abort() .

```
[code]
var CustomPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin;
  {your checking Access version and message box}
  Abort();
end;
```

Comment: @TLama is correct... I typed this off the top of my head then went to my codebase to grab a sample... forgetting the returning a Boolean would do the same as the abort!  Nice job TLama!

Comment: Since the script I'm using does the check in the initialize I use the Msgbox from TLama and the abort command in the initialize procedure and it work beautifully.  Thanks

Comment: @Mark, now I hope [`you can see`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12098613/960757) the difference between `InitializeSetup` and `InitializeWizard` events and how wasteful is to do this in `InitializeWizard`. In both you can raise your favorite silent exception.

Answer (score 6):

***Why to use InitializeSetup ?***

If you want to conditionally exit the setup before the wizard starts, don't use [`InitializeWizard`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm) event function with the [`Abort`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_abort.htm) exception raise. You'll be wasting your time, needed to create the whole wizard form. Use the [`InitializeSetup`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm) event function instead. There you can raise the [`Abort`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_abort.htm) exception or better return False to its boolean result, and exit the function as was supposed to do - the final effect will be definitely the same.

Internally, the [`InitializeSetup`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm) function, raises just this [`Abort`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_abort.htm) exception, when you return False to it from your script. Contrary to [`InitializeWizard`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm) event, when the [`InitializeSetup`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm) event is fired, the wizard form is not created yet, so you won't be wasting your time and never used system resources.

***Code example:***

In the following pseudo-code you need to have a function like `UserDownloadedWrongVersion` where, if you return True, the setup will be terminated, nothing happens oterwise.

```
[Code]
function UserDownloadedWrongVersion: Boolean;
begin
  // make your check here and return True when you detect a wrong 
  // version, what causes the setup to terminate; False otherwise
end;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not UserDownloadedWrongVersion;
  if not Result then
  begin
    MsgBox('You''ve downloaded the wrong version. Setup will now exit!', 
      mbError, MB_OK);
    Exit;   // <-- or use Abort; instead, but there's no need for panic
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you have some additional code you want to follow the above (but only when the setup is not being aborted): immediately after the `Result := False;` line in the first code block, place `exit;`.  This is the equivalent of a return statement in other languages -- it will immediately exit the function after having set the return value, and avoids having to put any remaining code in the function in an `else` block.  (And it's much "lighter" than `Abort()`.)  Or for the second example, place the `MsgBox` inside a `begin end` block and then put `exit;` following the `MsgBox`.

Comment: @Miral, yeah, you're right. I'll update this. Thanks! About the lightness of `InitializeSetup`, internally when you return False to `InitializeSetup`, the `Abort` is called inside. The main point is the form creation ;-)